Django. Почему форма не проходит валидацию?
Проблема в том, что форма не хочет ни при каких условиях проходить валидацию. Т.е. я ее заполняю, а данные не добавляются. Что я делаю не так? Минимально воспроизводимый пример ниже.
urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [

    path('template/upload', views.template_upload_view, name='template_upload'),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


views.py
from .forms import TemplateUploadForm

def template_upload_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TemplateUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Форма валидна. Добавляю данные в БД!")
            
    else:
        
        form = TemplateUploadForm

    return render(request, 'template_upload.html', {'form': form})

forms.py
from .models import Template

class TemplateUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Template
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'file',)

template_upload.html
<form method="post" id="chatbotAddForm" name="chatbotAddForm" action="/template/upload">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Add</button>
</form>

models.py
from django.db import models

class Template(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    uploaded_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

UPD: Вот код самой формы, сгенерированой Django
<form method="post" id="chatbotAddForm" name="chatbotAddForm" action="/template/upload">

    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="8sBCEXOuYnbcjqniJybaxBo5nAwW2hywh8Wrb9Izsz4FhjpNXhkMX2VwHcbOkBOi">

    <p>
      <label for="id_name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="255" id="id_name">
    </p>

  
    <p>
        <label for="id_description">Description:</label>
        <textarea name="description" cols="40" rows="10" required id="id_description">
       </textarea>
    </p>

  
    <p>
        <label for="id_file">File:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" required id="id_file">
    </p>

    <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Add</button> <a href="/chatbots"><input type="button" value="Cancel"></a>
</form>


Ну как минимум в показанном коде никакого добавления и нет. Если ваш вопрос о том, что условие if form.is_valid() не срабатывает и принт не принтится, значит читайте form.errors

@andreymal, да, я знаю, что нет. Я специально так сделал и убрал, минимально воспроизводимый пример как-никак. form.errors выводит This field is required для поля file

Вы забыли enctype="multipart/form-data" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files

Да, все так. Спасибо огромное за помощь!
